# Jquery ajax picture loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

Common situation. User clicks on the thumbnail, modal is opened, ajax request is made. On the success callback I do retrieve some info and html code with an image inside of it. And after that I want to center the image in modal wrap. The modal wrap is basically a full screen minus a div of width 320px from the right.  My code works but not always...sometimes happened that the picture is not centered correctly. Does anyone know where  the problem is ? The ".photo-media-part-image" is a class of my image from ajax success callback.

Check if image is loaded

```
jQuery.fn.isLoaded = function() {
    return this
        .filter("img")
        .filter(function() { return this.complete; }).length > 0;
};

// OPEN STATUS MEDIA MODAL
function openStatusMediaModal(e) {

    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
    var mediaModal = $('#mediaModal');

    $.ajax({
        success: function(data){
            mediaModal.find('.modal-body').html(data);

            tryMediaModalPictureVerticalAlign(mediaModal);

        },
        error: function(data) {
            ShowFlashMessagesBlockAfterAjax("Error");
        },
        complete: function() {

        }
    });
    return false;
}

function tryMediaModalPictureVerticalAlign(mediaModal) {
    if ($(".photo-media-part-image").isLoaded()) {
        var image = $(".photo-media-part-image");
        var imgHeight = image.height();
        var imgWidth = image.width();
        var wraper = $(window);

        // STOP THE LOADING ANIMATION
        loading('stop');

        // SHOW SMOOTHLY THE PICTURE
        image.animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: ((wraper.height()-imgHeight)/2)+'px',
            left: ((wraper.width()-320-imgWidth)/2)+'px'
        }, 300, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });

    } else {
        // try again
        setTimeout(function() {
            tryMediaModalPictureVerticalAlign(mediaModal);
        }, 200);

    }
}
```

I think the bug usually appear when I close the image and open it again. But not always...